# Forked project not appearing in dashboard

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, devops

I just forked a project, I made it a bluemix project with all the trimmings. But it is not showing up on my dashboard. I've confirmed I am looking at the right org and space for it.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What project did you fork?  Did you deploy the app back to Bluemix?  Once you fork the project you need to deploy the app.  You can do this by clicking on Build and Deploy and triggering the pipeline.

Comment: Oh that might be it, didn't know one had to do that. I am having to setup my pipeline, and am running it now. Bluemix is a tad sluggish this morning though...